# Error correcting codes and minimum distances

Tags: algorithm, matrix, error-correction

I was looking at a challenge online (at King's website) and although I understand the general idea behind it I'm slightly lost - maybe the wording is a little off? Here is the problem and I'll state what I don't understand below:

> Error correcting codes are used in a wide variety of applications
>   ranging from satellite communication to music CDs. The idea is to
>   encode a binary string of length k as a binary string of length n>k,
>   called a codeword such that even if some bit(s) of the encoding are
>   corrupted (if you scratch on your CD for instance), the original k-bit
>   string can still be recovered. There are three important parameters
>   associated with an error correcting code: the length of codewords (n),
>   the dimension (k) which is the length of the unencoded strings, and
>   finally the minimum distance (d) of the code. Distance between two
>   codewords is measured as hamming distance, i.e., the number of
>   positions in which the codewords differ: 0010 and 0100 are at distance
>   2. The minimum distance of the code is the distance between the two different codewords that are closest to each other. Linear codes are a
>   simple type of error correcting codes with several nice properties.
>   One of them being that the minmum distance is the smallest distance
>   any non-zero codeword has to the zero codeword (the codeword
>   consisting of n zeros always belongs to a linear code of length n).
>   Another nice property of linear codes of length n and dimension k is
>   that they can be described by an n×k generator matrix of zeros and
>   ones. Encoding a k-bit string is done by viewing it as a column vector
>   and multiplying it by the generator matrix. The example below shows a
>   generator matrix and how the string 1001 is encoded. graph.png Matrix
>   multiplication is done as usual except that additon is done modulo 2
>   (i.e., 0+1=1+0=1 and 0+0=1+1=0). The set of codewords of this code is
>   then simply all vectors that can be obtained by encoding all k-bit
>   strings in this way. Write a program to calculate the minimum distance
>   for several linear error correcting codes of length at most 30 and
>   dimension at most 15. Each code will be given as a generator matrix.
>   Input You will be given several generator matrices as input. The first
>   line contains an integer T indicating the number of test cases. The
>   first line of each test case gives the parameters n and k where
>   1≤n≤30, 1≤k≤15 and n > k, as two integers separated by a single space.
>   The following n lines describe a generator matrix. Each line is a row
>   of the matrix and has k space separated entries that are 0 or 1.
>   Output For each generator matrix output a single line with the minimum
>   distance of the corresponding linear code.

Sample Input 1

2

7 4

1 0 0 0

0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0

0 0 0 1

0 1 1 1

1 0 1 1

1 1 0 1

3 2

1 1

0 0

1 1

Sample Output 1

3

0

Now my assumption is that the question is asking "Write a program that can take in the linear code in matrix form and say what the minimum distance is from an all zero codeword" I just don't understand why there is a 3 output for the first input and a 0 for the second input?

Very confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first example:

```
Input binary string: 1000
Resulting code: 1100001
Hamming distance to zero codeword 0000000: 3
```

For second example:

```
Input binary string: 11
Resulting code: 000
Hamming distance to zero codeword 000: 0
```

Your goal is to find **valid** non-zero codeword (which can be produced from some non-zero k-bit input string) with minimal Hamming distance to zero codeword (in different words - with minimal amount of ones in binary representation) and return that distance.

Hope that helps, the problem description is indeed a little bit hard to understand.

**EDIT**. I've made typo in first example. Actual input should be **1**000 not 000**1**. Also it's may be not clear what exactly is input string and how the codeword is calculated. Let's look at first sample.

```
Input binary string: 1000
```

This binary string in general is **not** part of generator matrix. It is just one of all possible non-zero 4-bit strings. Let's multiply it by generator matrix:

```
(1 0 0 0) * (1 0 0 0) = 1
(0 1 0 0) * (1 0 0 0) = 0
(0 0 1 0) * (1 0 0 0) = 0
(0 0 0 1) * (1 0 0 0) = 0
(0 1 1 1) * (1 0 0 0) = 0
(1 0 1 1) * (1 0 0 0) = 1
(1 1 0 1) * (1 0 0 0) = 1
```

One way to find input that produces "minimal" codeword is to iterate all 2^k-1 non-zero k-bit strings and calculate codeword for each of them. This is feasible solution for k <= 15.

Another example for first test case 0011 (it's possible to have multiple inputs that produce "minimal" output):

```
(1 0 0 0) * (0 0 1 1) = 0
(0 1 0 0) * (0 0 1 1) = 0
(0 0 1 0) * (0 0 1 1) = 1
(0 0 0 1) * (0 0 1 1) = 1
(0 1 1 1) * (0 0 1 1) = 2 = 0 (mod 2)
(1 0 1 1) * (0 0 1 1) = 2 = 0 (mod 2)
(1 1 0 1) * (0 0 1 1) = 1
```

Resulting code 0011001 also has Hamming distance 3 to the zero codeword. There is no 4-bit string with code that has less that 3 ones in binary representation. That's why the answer for first test case is 3.

Comment: Thanks. The thing that is most puzzling is how did you choose the input binary string from the matrix, and how does that lead to the correct code?

Comment: @LloydCrawley Sorry for not really clear explanation. I've updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Also could you please clarify how many input binary strings should I try for finding non-zero codeword with minimal Hamming distance?

Comment: @SergeyVorobey For the provided constraints (k <= 15), trying all possible codes (up to 2^15 - 1) is feasible approach